# Objective C: Adaptive Toolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, user-interface

I want to create a toolbar without using the UIToolbar, instead I used image views and UIButtons but when I change the orientation of my iPad they remain where they are positioned.

Why didn't I use UIToolbar? Because I am having problems with the spacing of my buttons, because I want them closer to each other but on UIToolbar the space are wide.

If there is a way to change the spacing maybe I'll go back to UIToolbar.

Now, my question is how can I make the image views and UIButtons adaptive to the orientation?

Answer (score 1):

In interface builder, in your xib file, open size inpector.
There, use autosizing feature. arrows inside square are about resizing selected view. Liness outside of square are about getting origing point. You may allso change origin point's position there. just make all ypur objects to move/resize as you what there.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIToolbar and in between the buttons put a UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace and set its width using the width property.

[From the docs:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace Blank space to add between other
>   items. Only the width property is used when this value is set.

You can keep going with your own implementation of course, but users are expecting a toolbar to look and feel like a UIToolbar. Not only that, but it does everything you need it to do.

The general rule with apple provided UI elements is that they provide what you need, and if they don't, it is not hard to add what you need with a subclass. Starting from scratch is rarely needed.